# Problems with routing a Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that I am using to try and update a field on a 'thing', However, I'm getting massive problems that is probably down to something stupid.

My code is as follows:

```
<% form_for :thing, :url => { :action => "update" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :status_id, Thing.statuses, :first, :last %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

This looks correct to me (@thing does exist BTW), however, when I submit I get

```
Unknown action
No action responded to 145
```

etc etc etc.  The URL is http://localhost:3000/things/145. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using RESTful routing (and I'm assuming you are) you could just do this:

```
<% form_for @thing do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :status_id, Thing.statuses, :first, :last %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

And this will point to the correct action depending on if `@thing` is a `new_record?` or not.

Answer (score 4):

Using RESTful routes, the `update` action is triggered when a `put` request is recognized. You probably just need to specify the method as an html option:

```
form_for :thing, :url => { :action => "update" }, :html => { :method => 'put' } do |f|
```

Comment: Not the restful way to do it, could do form_for @thing and it would work. Much tidier too.

Answer (score 1):

I sort of despise ActionView so I'm always rusty when it comes to it, but try

```
<% form_for :thing, :url => 
     url_for(:action => "update", :id => @thing) do |f| %>
```

I'm sure someone else can come up with something DRYer and cleaner.

Comment: Any reason for the ActionView hate? ;)

Comment: Many. Could be an entirely separate SO question. But let's try to keep it small: erb sucks, I like haml; I'd prefer to use jQuery instead of Prototype, but helpers all generare Prototype code; I generally don't like the html output of the helpers anyway; It's dumb: view code is not aware of the view structure itself. For example I'd like a form to get it's multipart attribute set automatically when I add a file field. Can't do that. (Can't in haml either, but I have some amazing vapourware here that does this and much more. Hopefully one day it'll end up on github)